# Ограничение пределов изменения блока

Tags: html, css

Допустим, есть у меня форма, которую можно изменять за правый нижний уголок, а мне надо его поставить его в какой-нибудь блок, который не будет давать ему изменяться за его пределы.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, лучше с примером!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам поможет **UI resizable** — плагин jquery UI, который изменяет размеры элементов. Подробнее смотри **[тут](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#max-min)**. На странице показано именно то, что Вам нужно. Также имеется  исходный код примера, только не забудьте подключить библиотеки jQuery и jQuery UI.

P.S. У плагина имеется куча других интересных настроек, приводящих к интересным результатам. Подробнее о них можно почитать на той же странице, или, если не хотите на английском, то на

- http://www.linkexchanger.su/2009/109.html
- http://www.xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/ui/resizable.html

Comment: но хотелось бы решение на  html или css